# Active Routing Link in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I tried to make the Nav link change its color when the page is active only. I found 'Home' is always active. All links are ok i.e when the page is active the link is active and change its color.

```
<Nav>
    <Nav.Link><NavLink exact
        style={({ isActive }) => { return { color: isActive ? '#ffd900' : '' } }}
        className={this.state.navBarItem} to="/">HOME</NavLink></Nav.Link>


    <Nav.Link><NavLink exact
        style={({ isActive }) => { return { color: isActive ? '#ffd900' : '' } }}
        className={this.state.navBarItem} to="/about">ABOUT</NavLink></Nav.Link>

    <Nav.Link><NavLink exact
        style={({ isActive }) => { return { color: isActive ? '#ffd900' : '' } }}
        className={this.state.navBarItem} to="/service">SERVICE</NavLink></Nav.Link>

    <Nav.Link><NavLink exact
        style={({ isActive }) => { return { color: isActive ? '#ffd900' : '' } }}
        className={this.state.navBarItem} to="/course">COURSES</NavLink></Nav.Link>

    <Nav.Link><NavLink exact
        style={({ isActive }) => { return { color: isActive ? '#ffd900' : '' } }}
        className={this.state.navBarItem} to="/porfolio">PORTFOLIO</NavLink></Nav.Link>

    <Nav.Link><NavLink exact
        style={({ isActive }) => { return { color: isActive ? '#ffd900' : '' } }}
        className={this.state.navBarItem} to="/contact">CONTACT US</NavLink></Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which CSS Library/Framework you are using. Maybe your css Library/Framework has a built-in solution. My solution is given below:

Write before the return in component

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState('home')
const pages = ["home", "about", "service", "courses", "portfolio", "contact"]
```

Write inside the return of the component

```
<Nav>
{
  pages.map((page)=>(
    <Nav.Link>
    <NavLink exact
      style={{color: currentPage === page? '#ffd900': null}}
      className={this.state.navBarItem} to=`/${page}`
      onClick={()=>setCurrentPage(page)}
      >
      {page.toUpperCase()}
    </NavLink>
  </Nav.Link>
  ))
}
</Nav>
```